# How do I select either a th or a td from a table row?

Tags: html, ruby, css-selectors, nokogiri, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Nokogiri with Rails 5.  How do I select either a "th" element or a "td" element from a table row?  My goal is to get all the text of cells in a row (if there is a more generic, elegant solution, I'm all in).  Here's what I have

```
      text_all_rows = all_rows.map do |row|
        row_values = row.css('td | th').map{|str| str.text }
                                  .map{|str| str.gsub(/[[:space:]]+/, ' ').gsub(/\A\p{Space}+|\p{Space}+\z/, '') }.join("\t")
        [*row_values]
      end
```

As you may have noticed "td | th" is not valid syntax for selecting the "th" or "td" elements from the row.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". When asking a question like this we need you to supply the minimum input (HTML) that demonstrates the problem. Without that you force us to invent the input just to help you, which wastes our time and possibly introduces wobble in our answers. Don't do that, instead, help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `,` (comma) to select multiple nodes:

```
row_values = row.css('td, th').map{|str| str.text }
```

Comment: `map(&:text)` is more concise.