# How do I map a function to every element of my array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, strip

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  How do I map a complex function to every element in my array of strings?  The function is

```
elt.gsub!(/\A\p{Space}+|\p{Space}+\z/, '')
```

assuming "elt" is an element from my string array.  It is a glorified "strip" function.  I would like to apply it to every item in my array.

Comment: did you try `map`?

Comment: I nkow about .map(&:strip), but how would it work with a more complex function?

Comment: A few months ago you still knew it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44032605/1672429. And how do you have 138 Ruby questions and don't know how to use blocks?

Comment: @StefanPochmann I believe, based on his question history, that he mostly asks questions he knows the answer to for the sake of other viewers. This behavior, I believe, is not discouraged on SO. There are probably one or two meta topics about this sort of thing, and I've never seen it frowned upon.

Comment: Groovy, thx that did it.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo that’s completely fine because HRs knowing about SO already learned pretty well that accounts having 50+ gold badges with <100K rep are basically bots requiring no further attention.

Comment: @mudasobwa Whoa, never noticed that. Apparently it's far easier to get gold badges with basic questions than with answers? I guess my approach to SO is all wrong :-). But it's very hard for me to post a question, because when I have one, I almost always figure it out myself and/or find it treated on SO already...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is block syntax.

```
new_arr = arr.map { |elt| elt.gsub(/\A\p{Space}+|\p{Space}+\z/, '') }
```

Anything inside the braces will be treated as the "function" of `map`. For longer blocks, you can use `do .. end`

```
new_arr = arr.map do |elt|
  elt.gsub(/\A\p{Space}+|\p{Space}+\z/, '')
end
```

which is semantically equivalent.

Comment: Or even `mangle = ->(elt) { elt.gsub(...) }; arr.map(&mangle)` if the block is more complicated and would benefit from an explanatory name.

Comment: _Correction:_ `do end` is _almost_ semantically equivalent to `{}`, but _not_ _completely_. There is a drawback that is rarely taken into account, but they have **different precedence**. `puts [42].map { |e| e }` returns `42`, while `puts [42].map do |e| e end` surprisingly enough returns an `Enumerator` instance. [Details](http://rocket-science.ru/tips/2013/02/21/ruby-blocks-do-end-vs-braces).

Comment: @mudasobwa: No, Silvio is correct, they are semantically equivalent. Precedence is a question of syntax, not semantics.

Comment: @JörgWMittag two clauses returning different things could not be semantically equivalent, AFAIU.

Comment: The `do .. end` and `{ .. }` syntaxes are semantically equivalent. I still stand by my statement. The issue of operator precedence is resolved at parse-time. If you have an abstract syntax tree containing `do .. end` or `{ .. }`, you can always replace it with the opposite and get equivalent code.

Comment: But let's also notice that we're quite literally arguing semantics here and that the meaning is clear, regardless of whether or not we agree on the terminology used.

Answer (score 2):

If you know about `.map(&:strip)`, you probably know everything you need, the syntax does not differ for anything that is `proc` or might be converted to `proc` (read: responses to `#to_proc`.) `Symbol` responds to `#to_proc`, and that’s why `.map(&:strip)` works. `proc`s respond to `#to_proc`, returning self. That said, the following would perfectly work (`map` is not needed there (`each` is fine enough) since it’s using banged `grep!` that modifies everything inplace, but let it stay for the sake of consistence):

```
.map(&->(x) { x.gsub!(/\A\p{Space}+|\p{Space}+\z/, '') })
```

Comment: Does it have an advantage over the block solution? To me it only looks longer and more complicated. (I think I've seen you prefer this style before, that's why I'm asking.)

Comment: @StefanPochmann no, no, not at all, this particular snippet does not have any advantages (it has disadvantages :). I have posted this just to troll the OP (who is known to chase the rep with silly questions,) saying if they know how to use an ampersand notation, here they go. I prefer ampersand notation only when it’s more succinct, clearer and allows to DRY.